# correct preposition for "challenge"

Tags: prepositions

I am not sure about the preposition I used after "challenges" in this sentence. I wanted to point out the problem associated with using SLM technology, is "of" the correct choice?:

"The multiplicity of SLM parameters is one of the challenges of using this manufacturing technology"

Comment: Please include the research you have done.

Answer (score 0):

The scandalous depth of the English language means there are often many "correct" choices when constructing a sentence. In this particular context, your use of the preposition "of" is not incorrect and would be understood by the reader. A bit more nuance could be achieved via:

> The multiplicity of SLM parameters is one of the challenges **encountered while** using this manufacturing technology

or something similar.